# accessing arguments in an inner function argument (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arguments

Is there any possible way to obtain the arguments from a function that's been listed as an argument in another function? For example:

```
    function contract(preList,post,f) //where f is the function in question
{
        //get arguments of f and do something

}
```

In the function contract, preList checks if the arguments presented by f are numbers, and post checks if the result returned by f is a number.

Here is what the contract function would look like in use:

```
    var mult = contract(
             [isNumber, isNumber], //isNumber checks if input is number
              isNumber,
              function mult (x, y) {
                return x+y;
               });
```

I'm trying to access the x and y but I have very limited experience in javascript and I feel like I'm not asking the right questions to solve this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1) what are `arg1` and `arg2` in that second code block? 2) what is `other_function` in the first code block. 3) `example_fun` doesn't return anything, so `mult` will of course be undefined, because no `return` statement implies `return undefined` - it's not that you're asking the wrong question, it's that your code is full of errors

Comment: 4) `do_something` is declared inside `example_fun` ... where is it called?

Comment: Thanks for the input! I should've clarified that I put up the code to show the general structure of the function instead of expecting an actual output. I don't really care about arg1 and arg2 but instead wanted to put the focus on how f (mult in this case) was made and how I can access mult's arguments from inside example_fun! Hope this cleared things up!

Comment: the problem with that general code is, it's (no offence) garbage :p

Comment: No offense taken! then I'll post the actual code I'm trying to solve on the original. Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

I would make another function that contains function f with the parameters.  For example:
`function f_with_arg(){
        F(arg1, arg2)
}`. 
Then you replace `f` with `f_with_arg` to do this